# Folding over a list of Options to Find First or Last Some

Tags: scala, folding

I'm trying to fold over a list of Options in order return the first(or last) Some value or None if there aren't any Some values.

```
scala> val opts = List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2), None)
opts: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2), None)

scala> opts foldLeft(None)((a,io) => a match { case None => io; case Some(i) =>
a})
<console>:9: error: object None does not take parameters
              opts foldLeft(None)((a,io) => a match { case None => io; case Some
(i) => a})
                                 ^
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also there is probably a way to do this simpler using a higher order function but nothing from [here](http://dibblego.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) caught my eye.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your problem - the first element:

```
opts.flatten.headOption
```

And the last element:

```
opts.flatten.lastOption
```

`flatten` method will unbox all `Option` values in the list and drop all `None` values. `headOption`/`lastOption` will return either `Some` for the first/last element in the list or `None` if list is empty.

Answer (score 9):

[tenshi’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039261/folding-over-a-list-of-options-to-find-first-or-last-some/8039342#8039342) is pretty straightforward but for long lists it will attempt to flatten everything as it isn’t lazy. (I think `view` won’t help us here either but I’m not quite sure.)

In that case, you could use:

```
opts.dropWhile(_.isEmpty).headOption.flatMap(identity)
```

Unfortunately, we cannot use `flatten` here as this will return a generic `Iterable[Int]` and no `Option`, so we have to chose the longer idiom `flatMap(identity)`.

**Edit:** As [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115478/dave) noticed:

```
opts.find(_.isDefined).flatMap(identity)
```

would be even better.

Comment: It seems like find returns the first it finds. Is there a way to find the nth one or the last one in the list?

Comment: I think for the last one, you’d have to reverse the list before.

Comment: `opts.dropWhile(_.isEmpty).headOption` returns `Option[Option[Int]]`, right?! But why does a `flatten` on that double option not return `Option[Int]`? [ScalaDoc-Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Option) states by `ev: <:<[A, Option[B]]` that it should work with `A = Option[Int]` in our case.

Comment: @PeterSchmitz: You’re correct for the nightly build which the ScalaDoc is referring to. This will indeed be fixed for 2.10 (unless, of course, they revert the change for some reason). On the other hand in Scala 2.9 there is no method `flatten` on `Option` – only an implicit conversion to `Iterable` which gets executed in this case.

Comment: @Debilski Ah, great. I was confused while looking at nightly docs an having my code (2.9.1) react other than expected. Of course one should take the appropriate docs ;)

Comment: @Trevor The *efficient* way to get the last occurrence, it seems, is to define your collection as a `Vector` rather than a `List` thus: `val opts = Vector(...)` then use a `reverseIterator` to count back from the end: `opts.reverseIterator.find(_.isDefined).flatMap(identity)`.

Answer (score 4):

There are better ways to do it, but to answer the question as posed, you have two problems

1) You are missing the `.` following `opts`. You can only use infix notation to convert `a.m(b)` to `a m b`. The foldLeft method is of the form `a.m(b)(c)`. So either write it like that, or include parentheses `(a m b)(c)`.

2) You need to parameterize `None` as an `Option[Int]`: it's being interpreted here as the `None` object, rather than the value of an `Option[Int]` instance.

So this will work:

```
opts.foldLeft(None: Option[Int])(
  (a,io) => a match { case None => io; case Some(i) => a } )
```

Answer (score 2):

Why go to such trouble?

```
opts.find(_.nonEmpty).flatten
opts.reverse.find(_.nonEmpty).flatten
```

Comment: Because I'm still learning scala ... also is there a way to find the nth value?

Comment: @Trevor - `opts.view.filter(_.nonEmpty).drop(n-1).headOption.flatten` is a way to find the `n`th item without having to flatten the whole list.

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that `flatten` will return a `List` rather than an `Option` as the other answers do.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge You mean in the "nth" value case? Yeah, that example did not work. It would throw an exception, and return `List`. I removed it. But the code in the answer returns `Option` as expected.

Comment: Hmm, not for me it doesn't, in 2.9.0: it returns `Iterable[Int] = List(2)`. From Debilski's answer in his question, maybe this is a difference between 2.9 and 2.10.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge How disagreeable. Indeed, on trunk `Option` has a `flatten` method.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.9`, you can use [`collectFirst`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#collectFirst[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]) to extract the first defined option:

```
List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2), None).collectFirst { case Some(x) => x }
// Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

this will stop iterating at the first defined `Option` and avoids flattening the whole `List` before looking for its head.

---

Starting `Scala 2.13` you can use [`findLast`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#findLast(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]), which is the reverse of `find` (while waiting for a possible `collectLast`?)

```
List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2), None).findLast(_.isDefined).flatten
// Option[Int] = Some(2)
```