# Constructing an immutable graph with circular references

Tags: scala, immutability

I would like to model a simple graph where each node is connected to another node.

This seems like a reasonable definition of a node given the scenario:

```
case class Node(other: Node)
```

But say I want to create a graph that looks like this:

```
   --------------
   |            |
node_a          V
   ^          node_b
   |            |
   --------------
```

It appears impossible to create such a graph given the definition of `Node` because `other` is immutable and needs to be assigned on creation but it is impossible to create both nodes at the same time.

I suppose I could just store the name of the other node:

```
case class Node(name: String, otherName: String)
...
val n1 = Node("a", "b")
val n2 = Node("b", "a")
val nodes = Map(n1.name -> n1, n2.name -> n2)
```

This requires an additional step of generating a unique identifier per node. It's not terrible, but I really like the elegance of traversing the graph directly using the nodes themselves, a la `n.other` instead of `nodes.get(n.other)`.

Am I searching for the impossible here?

Answer (score 0):

This question from 2011 has a great answer that suggests a hack using laziness: [Scala: circular references in immutable data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374010/scala-circular-references-in-immutable-data-types)